# Getting Empty data after json_decode

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I using a Http Post method for Angular and I am getting an output as

```
data={"firstname":"sandeep","lastname":"chetikam","city":"Hyderabad","dateofbirth":"2017-06-08","gender":"Male"}
```

So i am json_decoding the data but i am not able to get the values from it .
When i Insert the data into Sql query. I am getting a empty values

PHP code:

```
<?php 
header('Aceess-Control-Header-Origin: *');
include('connect_db.php');
$post = json_decode($_POST['data']);
$id= "$post.id";
$firstname="$post.firstname";
$lastname="$post.lastname";
$dateofbirth="$post.dateofbirth";
$city="$post.city";
$gender="$post.gender";


$sql = "INSERT INTO employees(firstname,lastname,dateofbirth,city,gender) VALUES ("$firstname",".$lastname.",".$dateofbirth.",".$city.",".$gender.")";
if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    echo "DATA has been submitted";
}else{
    echo "error".mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo json_encode("Successful");
?>
```

Am i calling the data wrong ? How to call data values into my Sql query. Please help.

Modified :

```
    <?php 
    header('Aceess-Control-Header-Origin: *');
    include('connect_db.php');

    $post =json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
    $id= $post->id;
    $firstname=$post->firstname;
    $lastname=$post->lastname;
    $dateofbirth=$post->dateofbirth;
    $city=$post->city;
    $gender=$post->gender;


    $sql = "INSERT INTO employees(firstname,lastname,dateofbirth,city,gender) VALUES (".$firstname.",".$lastname.",".$dateofbirth.",".$city.",".$gender.")";
    if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
        echo "DATA has been submitted";
    }else{
        echo "error".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    echo json_encode("Successful");
    ?>
```

Now i am not getting any output from the query.

This is the output from my HTTP POST call : 
FORM Data:

```
data:{"firstname":"Dwqd","lastname":"chetikamqdqwdqwd","city":"Hyderabad","dateofbirth":"2017-06-02","gender":"Male"}
```

Comment: What is `"$post.id"`?

Comment: $post =json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

Comment: .... VALUES (".$firstname." .....

Comment: echo json_encode("Successful"); -> here something is wrong... Usually, users encodes the result of Query for using futher for other purposes

Comment: Is the data Format correct??

Answer (score 1):

php doesnt use the dot (.) character to access properties. You need to use the arrow ->. So to access the gender you use.

```
$gender = $post->gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **'->'** to get the object value in php and you miss to give **'.'** on our query

So just replace this

```
$id= "$post.id";
"INSERT INTO employees(firstname,lastname,dateofbirth,city,gender) VALUES ("$firstname",".$lastname.",".$dateofbirth.",".$city.",".$gender.")";
```

with

```
 $id= $post->id;
 "INSERT INTO employees(firstname,lastname,dateofbirth,city,gender) VALUES (".$firstname.",".$lastname.",".$dateofbirth.",".$city.",".$gender.")";
```

It will work for you.

Comment: Before empty data use to save in the table. Now the query is not getting called. It's not saving anything.

Comment: You modified your query ?

Comment: Yes..

 `<?php 
header('Aceess-Control-Header-Origin: *');
include('connect_db.php');
 
$post =json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
$id= $post->id;
$firstname=$post->firstname;
$lastname=$post->lastname;
$dateofbirth=$post->dateofbirth;
$city=$post->city;
$gender=$post->gender;


$sql = "INSERT INTO employees(firstname,lastname,dateofbirth,city,gender) VALUES (".$firstname.",".$lastname.",".$dateofbirth.",".$city.",".$gender.")";
if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
 echo "DATA has been submitted";
}else{
 echo "error".mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo json_encode("Successful");
?>`

Comment: Is the data format correct?? 
when i try to do it directly Its saying syntax error at ":", is it the wrong way to declare??

Comment: for that you can make the date and insert in to DB like  VALUES (".$firstname.",".$lastname.",'".$dateofbirth."',".$city.",".$‌​gender.")";